# JPQL - NamedQueries - How to convert a String to a Date type

Tags: java, sql, jpa, type-conversion, jpql

I have an @Column attribut called 'expirationDate' that is a String but I stock dates in it in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

I have a named query and I need to compare this attribut 'expirationDate' with the current_date

Example:
SELECT p FROM product p WHERE p.expirationDate >= current_date

And expirationDate is a String Type:

@Column(name = "expirationDate")
private String expirationDate;

Can you help me with this ? I need to convert p.expirationDate to a Date type in the query ...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably want to use a `@Converter` on that column. Not sure though at what point exactly it converts

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.